# Most efficient way to extract multiple key/value pairs from a list of dictionaries of dictionaries in Python?

Tags: python, dictionary

Below is the data I'm starting with. Ideally I would like to capture the 'raw' value of the 'avg', 'low', 'high' and 'numberOfAnalysts' keys from the first dictionary within this list of dictionaries, shown in **bold** (or captured between double asterisks (**) :

```
[**{'avg': {'raw': 3.02, 'fmt': '3.02'}, 'low': {'raw': 2.5, 'fmt': '2.5'}, 'high': {'raw': 3.15, 'fmt': '3.15'}, 'yearAgoEps': {'raw': 0.91, 'fmt': '0.91'}, 'numberOfAnalysts': {'raw': 20, 'fmt': '20', 'longFmt': '20'}, 'growth': {'raw': 2.319, 'fmt': '231.90%'}}**, {'avg': {'raw': 2.62, 'fmt': '2.62'}, 'low': {'raw': 2.36, 'fmt': '2.36'}, 'high': {'raw': 3.05, 'fmt': '3.05'}, 'yearAgoEps': {'raw': 2.92, 'fmt': '2.92'}, 'numberOfAnalysts': {'raw': 20, 'fmt': '20', 'longFmt': '20'}, 'growth': {'raw': -0.103, 'fmt': '-10.30%'}}, {'avg': {'raw': 10.14, 'fmt': '10.14'}, 'low': {'raw': 8.87, 'fmt': '8.87'}, 'high': {'raw': 10.68, 'fmt': '10.68'}, 'yearAgoEps': {'raw': 8.51, 'fmt': '8.51'}, 'numberOfAnalysts': {'raw': 26, 'fmt': '26', 'longFmt': '26'}, 'growth': {'raw': 0.192, 'fmt': '19.20%'}}, {'avg': {'raw': 11.67, 'fmt': '11.67'}, 'low': {'raw': 9.39, 'fmt': '9.39'}, 'high': {'raw': 13.08, 'fmt': '13.08'}, 'yearAgoEps': {'raw': 10.14, 'fmt': '10.14'}, 'numberOfAnalysts': {'raw': 26, 'fmt': '26', 'longFmt': '26'}, 'growth': {'raw': 0.15100001, 'fmt': '15.10%'}}, {'avg': {}, 'low': {}, 'high': {}, 'yearAgoEps': {}, 'numberOfAnalysts': {}, 'growth': {}}, {'avg': {}, 'low': {}, 'high': {}, 'yearAgoEps': {}, 'numberOfAnalysts': {}, 'growth': {}}]
```

I've used the following code to slice out the 'avg' key/value pairs, to start:

```
dispersion_analyst_data_final = dispersion_analyst_data_list_extract
dispersion_analyst_data_final_list_extract = [sub['avg'] for sub in dispersion_analyst_data_final]
print(str(dispersion_analyst_data_final_list_extract))
```

resulting in the output below:

```
[{'raw': 3.02, 'fmt': '3.02'}, {'raw': 2.62, 'fmt': '2.62'}, {'raw': 10.14, 'fmt': '10.14'}, {'raw': 11.67, 'fmt': '11.67'}, {}, {}]
```

I'm almost certain there is a more efficient way to drill down to the final 'raw' value without multiple discrete steps using sub(). The 'raw' values of the first dictionary of the 'avg', 'low', 'high' and 'numberOfAnalysts' data will ultimately be outputted to a CSV file. Is it possible to concatenate multiple sub() operations into the "extract" object?

The final desired data are the 'raw' values of 'avg', 'low', 'high' and 'numberOfAnalysts' within the first dictionary entry in dispersion_analyst_data_list_extract.  Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is variable **dispersion_analyst_data_list_extract** your original list?

Comment: I'm not sure what you want since your first paragraph implies you want to capture data just from the first dictionary, but your example output and list comprehension shows you're taking data from all the dictionaries.

Comment: Correct. The original starting point list is dispersion_analyst_data_list_extract. The variable dispersion_analyst_data_final_list_extract, is one step closer to extracting the aforementioned 'raw' values. I would like to see if this workflow can be better streamlined, based upon the original starting list dispersion_analyst_data_list_extract.

Comment: For the first dictionary in `dispersion_analyst_data_list_extract` are you trying to get the values associated with the keys: `'avg', 'low', 'high',  'numberOfAnalysts'`?

Comment: DarrylG, correct, and also in a more efficient/streamlined way

Comment: @jlakes85--since comment is correct, how is my posted answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mention--*The final desired data are the 'raw' values of 'avg', 'low', 'high' and 'numberOfAnalysts' within the first dictionary entry in dispersion_analyst_data_list_extract.*

That can be accomplished with the following.

```
dispersion_analyst_data_list_extract = [{'avg': {'raw': 3.02, 'fmt': '3.02'}, 'low': {'raw': 2.5, 'fmt': '2.5'}, 'high': {'raw': 3.15, 'fmt': '3.15'}, 'yearAgoEps': {'raw': 0.91, 'fmt': '0.91'}, 'numberOfAnalysts': {'raw': 20, 'fmt': '20', 'longFmt': '20'}, 'growth': {'raw': 2.319, 'fmt': '231.90%'}}, {'avg': {'raw': 2.62, 'fmt': '2.62'}, 'low': {'raw': 2.36, 'fmt': '2.36'}, 'high': {'raw': 3.05, 'fmt': '3.05'}, 'yearAgoEps': {'raw': 2.92, 'fmt': '2.92'}, 'numberOfAnalysts': {'raw': 20, 'fmt': '20', 'longFmt': '20'}, 'growth': {'raw': -0.103, 'fmt': '-10.30%'}}, {'avg': {'raw': 10.14, 'fmt': '10.14'}, 'low': {'raw': 8.87, 'fmt': '8.87'}, 'high': {'raw': 10.68, 'fmt': '10.68'}, 'yearAgoEps': {'raw': 8.51, 'fmt': '8.51'}, 'numberOfAnalysts': {'raw': 26, 'fmt': '26', 'longFmt': '26'}, 'growth': {'raw': 0.192, 'fmt': '19.20%'}}, {'avg': {'raw': 11.67, 'fmt': '11.67'}, 'low': {'raw': 9.39, 'fmt': '9.39'}, 'high': {'raw': 13.08, 'fmt': '13.08'}, 'yearAgoEps': {'raw': 10.14, 'fmt': '10.14'}, 'numberOfAnalysts': {'raw': 26, 'fmt': '26', 'longFmt': '26'}, 'growth': {'raw': 0.15100001, 'fmt': '15.10%'}}, {'avg': {}, 'low': {}, 'high': {}, 'yearAgoEps': {}, 'numberOfAnalysts': {}, 'growth': {}}, {'avg': {}, 'low': {}, 'high': {}, 'yearAgoEps': {}, 'numberOfAnalysts': {}, 'growth': {}}]

# dispersion_analyst_data_list_extract[0] is the first dictionary
# we access its desired keys using a list comprehension of the first dictionary
desired_output = [dispersion_analyst_data_list_extract[0][k] for k in ['avg', 'low', 'high',  'numberOfAnalysts']]

print(desired_output)
# Out: [{'raw': 3.02, 'fmt': '3.02'},
        {'raw': 2.5, 'fmt': '2.5'},
        {'raw': 3.15, 'fmt': '3.15'},
        {'raw': 20, 'fmt': '20', 'longFmt': '20'}]
```